# C Program in visual studio. Array with a constant value is treated as an error

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, compiler-errors, constants

I've tried looking for a solution to this problem, but with no luck.
I have a program written in C, and in it I have an array that is defined like this:

```
int sevensArray[SEVENS_COUNT];
```

When compiling it I get an error that says "`Expression must be of constant value`".

I realize you cannot have the array size to be a variable, as the compiler should know how much memory it needs to allocate.
The thing is... `SEVENS_COUNT` is defined as a `const INT` in the program like so:

```
const int SEVENS_COUNT = counter;
```

My question is why is this still seen as an error. Is it because even though `SEVENS_COUNT` is a `const` it is assigned to counter, which is actually a variable and how can I fix that.

I tried the same code and it compiles perfectly fine on other compilers such as Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 2):

`const` doesn't mean *constant*, but *read-only*.

**1)** Best way: make it dynamic instead of static. Use `malloc` or if you want it additionally initialized `calloc`. At the end don't forget to free the allocated memory.

You would need a pointer however instead of an array, but for *your purpose* they are essentially the same. Like:

```
int *sevensPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * counter);
//your code
free(sevensPtr);
```

If you don't know how to access an element from the allocated memory, it is analogous to array:

```
sevensArray[0] == sevensPtr[0] == *(sevensPtr + 0)
```

**2)** Another way is to use **VLA**s. Then you could assign a variable-length to your array. Such as:

```
 void foo(int n)  //and pass counter
 {
   int x[n];
   process(x, n); 
 }
```

In words, pass it as an argument of a/the function and then declare the array locally.

Also you could simply use `alloca`.

As about the IDE, the one supports variable-size declaration, whereas the other doesn't. But that depends on the C standard being used and not on the environment itself.

Comment: Only automatic VLAs are valid; at file scope you cannot use a VLA. But the other IDE could be using C++,  which doesn't have VLAs, but which does allow a constant expression to be used as an array bound.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it must live and die in the function, locally. Yes, thought of it(C++).